Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
In my project, we're using Spring XML config (no scope to use Spring Boot for now), I am looking to implement the Kafka consumer with the good exception handling and retry mechanism.
Also, wanted to explore out of the box exception handling and custom exception handling , same looking to explore for retry.
The problem is I dont see XML snippet and working code around.
Case-1: I am looking to implement the out of the box exception handling, below is the code, but I am getting error endless loop exception for junk data.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition t-employee-0 at offset 4. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1666)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1330)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data  from topic [t-employee]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:588)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

context.xml file

<bean id="employeeProducer" class="com.example.kafka.producer.EmployeeProducer" />

<bean id="defaultKafkaConsumerFactory" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="spring.json.trusted.packages" value="*" />
            <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092"/>
            <entry key="auto.offset.reset" value="latest"/>
            <entry key="group.id" value="group1" />
            <entry key="client.id" value="my-client-id" />
            <entry key="max.poll.records" value="1"/>
            <entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer" />
            <entry key="value.deserializer" value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer" />
            <entry key="spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class" value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer" />
            <entry key="spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class" value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer" />
            <entry key="value.class.name" value="com.example.kafka.model.Employee" />
            <entry key="spring.json.value.default.type" value="com.example.kafka.model.Employee" />

            <entry key="spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers" value="false" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="keyDeserializer" class="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="valueDeserializer" class="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="containerProperties" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties">
    <constructor-arg name="topics" value="t-employee"/>
    <property name="groupId" value="group1"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myListener"  />
</bean>

<bean id="containerListener" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="defaultKafkaConsumerFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="containerProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="myListener" class="com.example.kafka.listener.MyMessageListener" />

I'm not clear on if JsonDeserializer has to be configured on the ConsumerFactory and Properties as well (dont have much clarity around that) or I dont see the way to do it in XML, could anyone please guide?
Main concern is junk data ending up into endless loop.

Unfortunately I'm not entirely sure about your current situation, but I'll try my best to help you out on what seems rather clear to me.
Starting from the question

I'm not clear on if JsonDeserializer has to be configured on the ConsumerFactory and Properties as well [...]

It doesn't have to be done in both of the places, it all depends on which constructor do you want to use. See DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory class docs - if you don't provide other arguments and leave it in the map, it'll just use another constructor.
After that things start to get tricky: I understand that you want to debug why your app is not deserializing anything. Depending on your situation I would try to consider:

Implementing your own CommonErrorHandler (see docs) that you'll then register in your context as bean (by adding it to your XML). It is a standard way to try to handle some of the exceptions of a certain type. Additionally if your context is making use of external app (e.g. a JAR that you're only adding to the project and cannot see the sources of) it should still let you to freely add it to the context (and therefore to the Kafka Consumer). There is a good example of how it can be done here too.

If - however - you don't have option to add such handler, you can still try to use StringDeserializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer) or even Bytes deserializer in order to find some of the answers. This exception you have seems to suggest that your app couldn't make a JSON out of it, so maybe if you could try more generic types it could point you in the right direction (maybe it's not JSON but YML/XML?). Plus - to be honest - I've never seen key to be a JSON (most of the times it's either some kind of ID like integer or UUID which will be String), are you sure that's correct? I'm referring to this part:
        <entry key="spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class" value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer" />



while couple lines below it it seems it's a String:
        <bean id="keyDeserializer" class="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />


Last but not least: there is someone writing to this topic that maybe you could ask for help? It seems stupid maybe, but if the topic is using some more-sophisticated types of data in it (like Apache Avro with it's own schema or maybe it's a compacted topic where old data is tombstoned) it's going to be either gathering information from the producer or a long process of figuring it out yourself (which can be done if properly looking at bytes, but let's face it: we wouldn't like to do that, right?)

This way or another: good luck and hope you'll be able to find the right format soon!

sorry for the lates response, I was off sick. I've uploaded the project: https://github.com/javaHelper/kafka-project. Could you please check and suggest the solution. I'd be happy to accept it
